# Erlang check empty string

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I'm new in Erlang development. I'm trying to read value of AccessToken from mnesia table (stored in 'users' table).

In my code I've done:

```
BUser = boss_db:find(users, [{email, 'equals', MyEmail}]),
[{_,_,BEmail,BName,BPassword,_,BAccessToken}] = BUser,
io:format("User Details ~n~p~n", [BUser]),
io:format("Access Token ~n~p~n", [BAccessToken]),
.
.
```

I get:

```
User Details 
[{users,"users-1","mymail@someemail.org","Some Name","somepassword",'',''}]
```

The Last field is AccessToken and it is printed as:

```
Access Token 
''
```

If AccessToken value is non empty I'll do some operation.

How do I check if AccessToken is empty or not?

I tried:

```
AccessTokenLength = length(BAccessToken)
if AccessTokenLength > 0 ->
.
.
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in controller error badarg [{erlang,length,[''],[]}
```

I also tried:

```
case binary_to_list(BAccessToken) =/= [] of
true->
false->
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in controller error badarg [{erlang,binary_to_list,[''],[]}
```

How do I check the empty condition properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pattern match on value

```
case BAccessToken of
     '' ->
         %% empty 
     _ ->
         %% not empty
end
```

And one more thing.  Single quotes in Erlang signifies atom.  Usually you can write those with starting lover case letter, like `atom` or `false` or `not_empty`.  But sometimes you would like to use some more "complex" atom you could use single quote like `'This is also atom'`.  And `''` is just "empty atom.

And empty binary would look like this `<<>>`.